# C# multiple choice question with radiobutton

Tags: c#, validation, radio-button, user-input

so I'm new to programming still learning I have to create multiple-choice questions so I made a method that outputs questions and answers but I don't know how to validate my answers if the button check is clicked.will be glad if some experts here could give me an idea.

```
public partial class Form1: Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void PresentQuestion()
    {
        radioButton1.Checked = false;
        radioButton2.Checked = false;
        radioButton3.Checked = false;
        radioButton4.Checked = false;
        Random rand = new Random();
        int cycles = rand.Next(1, 4);

        switch (cycles)
        {
            case 1:
                textBox1.Text = "what is 15 - 8 ?";


                radioButton1.Text = "A. 6";
                radioButton2.Text = "B. 7";
                radioButton3.Text = "C. 5";
                radioButton4.Text = "D. 4";

                break;

            case 2:
                textBox1.Text = "what is 5 x 5?";

                radioButton1.Text = "A. 25";
                radioButton2.Text = "B. 50";
                radioButton3.Text = "C. 20";
                radioButton4.Text = "D. 100";


                break;

            case 3:
                textBox1.Text = "what is 4+4?";

                radioButton1.Text = "A. 4";
                radioButton2.Text = "B. 2";
                radioButton3.Text = "C. 2";
                radioButton4.Text = "D. 8";

                break;
        }
    }


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PresentQuestion();
    }

    private void buttonCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PresentQuestion();


    }
}
```

}

Comment: This looks suspiciously like _homework_.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this ...

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    int cycles = 0;

    private void PresentQuestion(int cycles)
    {
        switch (cycles)
        {
            case 1:
                textBox1.Text = "what is 15 - 8 ?";

                radioButton1.Text = "A. 6";
                radioButton2.Text = "B. 7";
                radioButton3.Text = "C. 5";
                radioButton4.Text = "D. 4";

                break;

            case 2:
                textBox1.Text = "what is 5 x 5?";

                radioButton1.Text = "A. 25";
                radioButton2.Text = "B. 50";
                radioButton3.Text = "C. 20";
                radioButton4.Text = "D. 100";


                break;

            case 3:
                textBox1.Text = "what is 2+2?";

                radioButton1.Text = "A. 4";
                radioButton2.Text = "B. 2";
                radioButton3.Text = "C. 2";
                radioButton4.Text = "D. 8";

                break;
        }
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (cycles)
        {
            case 1:
                if(radioButton2.Checked)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("correct");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("wrong");
                }
                break;

            case 2:
                if (radioButton1.Checked)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("correct");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("wrong");
                }
                break;

            case 3:
                if (radioButton1.Checked)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("correct");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("wrong");
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        radioButton1.Checked = false;
        radioButton2.Checked = false;
        radioButton3.Checked = false;
        radioButton4.Checked = false;

        Random rand = new Random();
        cycles = rand.Next(1, 4);

        PresentQuestion(cycles);
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Consider improving your answer. _[Code-only answers may fall under 'Very Low Quality' ...and are candidates for deletion....We've always touted that we aren't a code factory. We are the people who teach others to fish. Code-only answers only feed a person for a day](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques)_

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int total = 0;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void PresentQuestion()
    {
        radioButton1.Checked = false;
        radioButton2.Checked = false;
        radioButton3.Checked = false;
        radioButton4.Checked = false;
        Random rand = new Random();
        int cycles = rand.Next(1, 4);

        switch (cycles)
        {
            case 1:
                textBox1.Text = "what is 15 - 8 ?";
                total = 15 - 8;

                radioButton1.Text = "6";
                radioButton2.Text = "7";
                radioButton3.Text = "5";
                radioButton4.Text = "4";

                break;

            case 2:
                textBox1.Text = "what is 5 x 5?";
                total = 5 * 5;
                radioButton1.Text = "25";
                radioButton2.Text = "50";
                radioButton3.Text = "20";
                radioButton4.Text = "100";


                break;

            case 3:
                textBox1.Text = "what is 2+2?";
                total = 2 + 2;
                radioButton1.Text = "4";
                radioButton2.Text = "2";
                radioButton3.Text = "2";
                radioButton4.Text = "8";

                break;
        }
    }

    private bool CheckOFResult()
    {
        foreach(Control r in this.Controls)
        {
            if(r.GetType() == typeof(RadioButton))
            {
                RadioButton radio = (RadioButton)r;
                if (radio.Checked)
                {
                    if (int.Parse(radio.Text) == total)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PresentQuestion();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CheckOFResult())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Correct");
        }else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect");
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PresentQuestion();
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider improving your answer. _[Code-only answers may fall under 'Very Low Quality' ...and are candidates for deletion....We've always touted that we aren't a code factory. We are the people who teach others to fish. Code-only answers only feed a person for a day](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques)_